# Azure, group policy on azure as on-premises

Tags: azure, gpo, intune

Is there any way to deploy some policies to the client on Azure as on-premises?
dig some and found that Azure AD and Intune do some. but I need exactly what on-premises GPO does.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy site-to-site VPN. So that the VMs on Azure are connected to the corpnet directly. Then you are able to join these VMs into the domain.

To create site-to-site VPN, please follow this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal/).

Comment: thanx steven, but i need physical device(windows 10 laptops or desktops)